# Why Jupyter can't read csv files when they are in folders?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, storage

today I struggle to make Jupyter read a csv file I have downloaded. When it was saved like this `"C:\Users\argir\state.csv"` `Jupyter` was able to read it. (`photo: https://ibb.co/qYLmWb0` ). But when I put it in a folder and the path was "`C:\Users\argir\datasets_dika_mou\state.csv`" (photo: https://ibb.co/mBVQS3f ) or when it was saved in another folder on the desktop and the path was `C:\Users\argir\Υπολογιστής\datasets` from 50 practical-statistics-for-data-scientistsebook `oreilly\state.csv`" (photo: https://ibb.co/M7m3PTF ) the Jupyter couldn't read it

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'state.csv'
> Why does this happen?

```py
import pandas as pd
state_data = pd.read_csv("state.csv")
```

Comment: Can you post the code which you use for reading?

Comment: You should edit your question with the relevant parts of your code so we can help you.

Comment: Yes kindly update the question with more info and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you put into the comment, it could be that you simply not defining the path to the file.

When your file is at the same directory as the Notebook your code will work, but when the file is not at the same path you have to tell python where to look.

like:

```py
import pandas as pd
state_data = pd.read_csv("datasets_dika_mou/state.csv")
```